# Why Does My Object Not Transfer To The Next VC?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to transfer my object from HockeyDetailVC to my FavouritesVC using a button but my object is nil when I reach my second VC FavouritesVC. Why is it like that when I set the variable in my firstVC with my func transferObj()?

**HockeyDetailVC**

```
var item: CurrentPlayers?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gonnaLoadView()
        tableV.bounces = false
        tableV.alwaysBounceVertical = false
        favButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        print(item)    *//prints my current players object*
    }

   func transferObj() {
        let otherVC = FavouritesVC()
        otherVC.currentFav = item
        print(item).  *//prints my current player object*
    }

  @IBAction func addToFav(_ sender: Any) {
    transferObj()
    print("Favourite button Pressed")
}
```

**FavouritesVC**

```
  var currentFav: CurrentPlayers?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if currentFav == nil {
    //display nil
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none
    print(favArr)    *//prints empty array*
    print(currentFav) *//nil*
    } else {
    favArr.append(currentFav!)
    print(favArr)
    }
}
```

Comment: `let otherVC = FavouritesVC()` creates a *new instance* of the controller, it does not give you a reference to the presented view controller. There are several similar Q&As already, see for example  https://stackoverflow.com/q/47271711/1187415 (and also https://stackoverflow.com/q/5210535/1187415).

Comment: How do you present `FavouritesVC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Martin stated, `let otherVC = FavouritesVC()` creates a new instance of the controller, but it is not the instance that you will eventually display. So you are effectively setting the `currentFav` of a random FavouritesVC that will never actually be displayed, while the one you eventually *do* navigate to has it's `currentFav` property still unset.

To set the appropriate FavouritesVC instance, you need to access it in one of several ways (depending on how you present it). If it is through a segue, then you can reference it in the `prepare(for segue: sender:)` method. (When you create a Cocoa Touch Class file, the below method template is pre-populated. As it states, reference the new view controller using segue.destination.)

```
/*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */
```

Alternatively, if you create and present the new view controller programmatically with something like

```
// 1.
let otherVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourFavouritesVCIdentifier")

// 2.

// 3.
self.show(otherVC, sender: self)
```

you can insert your `otherVC.currentFav = item` at line `// 2.`.